# ADFS call: (411) Length Required

Tags: c#, adfs2.0

I'm trying to get a SAML token from an ADFS instance. I followed the example found here (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/willpe/archive/2010/10/25/windows-authentication-adfs-and-the-access-control-service.aspx) to configure everything. The ADFS instance is configured by a different party, but setup as found in the article.

At first sight, it all seems to be working ok. But when I go into code and run a sample which should get me a token, I receive a (411) Length Required) response from the server. It doesn't matter much if I switch endpoints, errors stays the same. Seems like the response isn't even getting to the endpoint at all.

The Length Required error seems to have something to do with a missing Content-Length: 0 header line. I checked with Fiddler; it's not there. But the call is generated from within the .NET framework, so there really isn't that much I can do about that.

Any idea why the server might throw this error? Should I try to change the request, or disable the check on the server side? Or an option I haven't thought of perhaps?

Comment: Is this line `byte[] responseBytes = client.UploadValues("", parameters);` the one that raises the exception?

Comment: Could you post the part of your code which corresponds to the `GetSwtToken` method from the provided URL reference?

Comment: Hello Alex, I'm not sure. The exception occurs on the line where I do my method call to the webservice. The exception is then generated somewhere within .net framework classes. So I can't really post code of those.

Comment: Have you tried adding the `Content-Length` header to the request?

Comment: How would I do that when the entire request is generated by the framework and doesn't surface? I have no way to alter the request as far as I know.